# Lost data when switching from windows to ubuntu

Tags: windows, data-recovery

When I had windows 10, i had 3 partitions, C, D and E, C was the OS partition and D & E stored my data, now when i installed ubuntu i wiped C and put the D&E to "Do not use this partition" also i switched from NTSF to ext2, when i finished installing, i mounted the D & E drives and nothing was in them. What could've happened? Please help me.

```
Any help would be appreciated
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Im not sure, im also not sure if my data is completely lost.... im honestly panicking and don't know what to do

Comment: where you 100% sure your data where on your D and E partitions?
You should try to access the memory from a Ubuntu live just to verify the problem is not in the mounting process. And how do you mount these partitions?

Comment: Yes they were on D and E partitions. Im gonna try from live rn

Comment: When you said, "switched from NTFS to EXT2" that doesn't make any sense. I hope you didn't reformat one of your data partitions like that, or you lost the data.